# Could Not find Crash in apple symbolicating carsh reports in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios9.1

How do I learn which device was used by the Apple team to test the app. In crash reports they mentioned Hardware Model: xxx.

Does anyone know how to find the Hardware Model used by the Apple team?

```
Incident Identifier: B9357CD3-97A1-455B-8B72-B1216DB3F475
CrashReporter Key:   2315aec9ade195d48aee1994bc1df30f6a85a64c
Hardware Model:      iPad5,4
Process:             Blissbooker [1435]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/852C1823-83A2-4BC1-BF16-CDBDF8F26414/Blissbooker.app/Blissbooker
Identifier:          com.Organization.BlissBookerAppID
Version:             1.0 (2.9.14)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-06-21 17:33:57.57 -0700
Launch Time:         2016-06-21 17:33:08.08 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 9.3.2 (13F69)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x183012db0 0x182677f80 0x183019c4c 0x183016bec 0x182f14c5c 0x1000bc334 0x188168c40 0x1881810d0 0x18831be5c 0x188227e40 0x188227b1c 0x188227a84 0x1881641e4 0x185af6994 0x185af15d0 0x185af1490 0x185af0ac0 0x185af0820 0x185ae9de4 0x182fc8728 0x182fc64cc 0x182fc68fc 0x182ef0c50 0x1847d8088 0x1881d2088 0x1000593d4 0x182a8e8b8)

Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
2.150634     CFNetwork                  0x00000001835f5a80 TCP Conn 0x147ea3260 SSL Handshake DONE
2.241144     CFNetwork                  0x00000001835f5990 TCP Conn 0x147ea3260 starting SSL negotiation
2.241445     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183697f18 TCP Conn 0x147ea3260 complete. fd: 12, err: 0
2.242224     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183699444 TCP Conn 0x147ea3260 event 1. err: 0
2.351253     CFNetwork                  0x000000018369951c TCP Conn 0x147ea3260 started
3.268228     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183697f18 TCP Conn 0x149c08d40 complete. fd: 7, err: 0
3.268503     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183699444 TCP Conn 0x149c08d40 event 1. err: 0
3.360390     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183697f18 TCP Conn 0x147f75eb0 complete. fd: 4, err: 0
3.361856     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183699444 TCP Conn 0x147f75eb0 event 1. err: 0
3.378858     CFNetwork                  0x000000018369951c TCP Conn 0x149c08d40 started
3.381795     CFNetwork                  0x000000018369951c TCP Conn 0x147f75eb0 started
6.699630     AppleJPEG                  0x0000000184a72a88 [0x148060800] Releasing session
8.580608     CFNetwork                  0x00000001835f5a80 TCP Conn 0x147f8b830 SSL Handshake DONE
8.608402     CFNetwork                  0x00000001835f5990 TCP Conn 0x147f8b830 starting SSL negotiation
8.608727     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183697f18 TCP Conn 0x147f8b830 complete. fd: 4, err: 0
8.608995     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183699444 TCP Conn 0x147f8b830 event 1. err: 0
8.644997     CFNetwork                  0x000000018369951c TCP Conn 0x147f8b830 started
15.882712    CFNetwork                  0x00000001835f5a80 TCP Conn 0x147f698c0 SSL Handshake DONE
15.912782    CFNetwork                  0x00000001835f5990 TCP Conn 0x147f698c0 starting SSL negotiation
15.913278    CFNetwork                  0x0000000183697f18 TCP Conn 0x147f698c0 complete. fd: 8, err: 0
15.913674    CFNetwork                  0x0000000183699444 TCP Conn 0x147f698c0 event 1. err: 0



Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182bac11c 0x182b90000 + 114972
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182c78ef8 0x182c74000 + 20216
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000182b1ddac 0x182abc000 + 400812
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001826513f4 0x182650000 + 5108
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018266de98 0x182650000 + 122520
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000182678248 0x182670000 + 33352
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018266af44 0x182650000 + 110404
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018266ab10 0x182650000 + 109328
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000182678120 0x182670000 + 33056
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182ef0cf8 0x182ee8000 + 36088
10  GraphicsServices                0x00000001847d8088 0x1847cc000 + 49288
11  UIKit                           0x00000001881d2088 0x188154000 + 516232
12  Blissbooker                     0x00000001000593d4 0x100030000 + 168916
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000182a8e8b8 0x182a8c000 + 10424

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182bad4d8 0x182b90000 + 120024
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182a707d8 0x182a5c000 + 83928
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182a5f648 0x182a5c000 + 13896

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182bacb48 0x182b90000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182c75530 0x182c74000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182c75020 0x182c74000 + 4128

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182b90fd8 0x182b90000 + 4056
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182b90e54 0x182b90000 + 3668
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182fc8c60 0x182ee8000 + 920672
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182fc6964 0x182ee8000 + 911716
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182ef0c50 0x182ee8000 + 35920
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000183671c68 0x1835c4000 + 711784
6   Foundation                      0x00000001839e7e4c 0x1838f4000 + 998988
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182c77b28 0x182c74000 + 15144
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182c77a8c 0x182c74000 + 14988
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182c75028 0x182c74000 + 4136

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182bac344 0x182b90000 + 115524
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182fcf1c8 0x182ee8000 + 946632
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182c77b28 0x182c74000 + 15144
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182c77a8c 0x182c74000 + 14988
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182c75028 0x182c74000 + 4136

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182bacb48 0x182b90000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182c75530 0x182c74000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182c75020 0x182c74000 + 4128

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182bacb48 0x182b90000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182c75530 0x182c74000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182c75020 0x182c74000 + 4128

Thread 7 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182bac41c 0x182b90000 + 115740
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000182ac922c 0x182abc000 + 53804
2   Foundation                      0x00000001839e72f8 0x1838f4000 + 996088
3   Blissbooker                     0x00000001002f605c 0x100030000 + 2908252
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182a5d4bc 0x182a5c000 + 5308
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182a5d47c 0x182a5c000 + 5244
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182a6b914 0x182a5c000 + 63764
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182a6b0b0 0x182a5c000 + 61616
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182c75470 0x182c74000 + 5232
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182c75020 0x182c74000 + 4128

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182bacb48 0x182b90000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182c75530 0x182c74000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182c75020 0x182c74000 + 4128

Thread 9:

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000147eb72a7
    x4: 0x000000018266ee02   x5: 0x000000016fdcf4e0   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000fa0
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000000002  x11: 0x0000000000000010
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000002  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x0000030000000300
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001a1263000  x21: 0x000000016fdcf4e0  x22: 0x0000000147f13660  x23: 0x00000001a126f150
   x24: 0x0000000000000001  x25: 0x89003b55167c6d50  x26: 0x0000000147f12e20  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x0000000000000001  fp: 0x000000016fdcf440   lr: 0x0000000182c78ef8
    sp: 0x000000016fdcf420   pc: 0x0000000182bac11c cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x100030000 - 0x1003fffff Blissbooker arm64  <0df4d9c044783a64952a60f599ac2987> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/852C1823-83A2-4BC1-BF16-CDBDF8F26414/Blissbooker.app/Blissbooker
0x1200d4000 - 0x120103fff dyld arm64  <488b8b4696fb312db76da956e6f5aef5> /usr/lib/dyld
0x1825f8000 - 0x1825f9fff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <77c873c418a6317f821f7b706d5b7dc6> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x1825fc000 - 0x18264efff libc++.1.dylib arm64  <9ec0d9dcf728349582c26a7da72f0364> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x182650000 - 0x18266ffff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <aaa40b7f52513cf79c6f814b133556a7> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x182670000 - 0x1829dcfff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <939f392022903f2da2858e676e4191ef> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x1829e0000 - 0x1829e4fff libcache.dylib arm64  <43424f4c7252330ca92c1a865da896e1> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x1829e8000 - 0x1829f3fff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64  <e47d758d207e32c8ab546b59785d2ab8> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x1829f4000 - 0x1829f7fff libcompiler_rt.dylib arm64  <b77c451c7ffb356fb3c8368cac95d8f3> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x1829f8000 - 0x1829fffff libcopyfile.dylib arm64  <1c1678aa36073b42b4406c6dbb06e9f0> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x182a00000 - 0x182a5bfff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64  <b42ff635d1303d45bafe057e5a1e6243> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x182a5c000 - 0x182a8afff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <65568801b7463adeb6e20dc25d14d801> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x182a8c000 - 0x182a8efff libdyld.dylib arm64  <e1f151766d6e3755a1a59f62d9a3d9f9> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x182a90000 - 0x182a90fff liblaunch.dylib arm64  <fbb5f1442c3039188da689963efde4d8> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x182a94000 - 0x182a98fff libmacho.dylib arm64  <1f37b179ad26307192b3b763ba5f816a> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x182a9c000 - 0x182a9dfff libremovefile.dylib arm64  <267c6cbaf2193309bd8a191fad38cc79> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x182aa0000 - 0x182ab6fff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64  <fffe50d37b1c3f92af6f4a68a6d60068> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x182ab8000 - 0x182ab9fff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <8bbf799e57f93ed1be24cf2ce6c221a3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x182abc000 - 0x182b3bfff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <a05dd3ed96153b1bb2da1954a08d4d23> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x182b3c000 - 0x182b3ffff libsystem_configuration.dylib arm64  <c5ce1ced5659354ab63871b42d04a7cd> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x182b40000 - 0x182b43fff libsystem_containermanager.dylib arm64  <504648cfa43d3668b9678b74e33697f2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
0x182b44000 - 0x182b45fff libsystem_coreservices.dylib arm64  <8f94549c633036aa99efb0f067031a05> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x182b48000 - 0x182b5efff libsystem_coretls.dylib arm64  <498e424eb31f3d5cb49523cec07f339d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
0x182b60000 - 0x182b68fff libsystem_dnssd.dylib arm64  <096026a14628397ea96580ce7704f39e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x182b6c000 - 0x182b8efff libsystem_info.dylib arm64  <932df5ba705a3b6d948c5dcff196ea6b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x182b90000 - 0x182bb1fff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <29df8d8d12d034ffa906bb02f04610f4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x182bb4000 - 0x182bd0fff libsystem_m.dylib arm64  <a97bf91d4a233dbc94bef06734a2eac0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x182bd4000 - 0x182bedfff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64  <a8af95191b283ca9aa7f9cf80c459bf5> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x182bf0000 - 0x182c53fff libsystem_network.dylib arm64  <a8e4200aecc73e56a8458a0e9cb4a6f0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x182c54000 - 0x182c5dfff libsystem_networkextension.dylib arm64  <d1a7579c71943631845c2908d69bfbc6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x182c60000 - 0x182c6afff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64  <da8d7d155da230d287a67c46e9b3ccbc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x182c6c000 - 0x182c71fff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <4386956061113d7a9e415e543b1243bc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x182c74000 - 0x182c7cfff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <7965d331db2c3bd2b8cbc1bc78babca2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x182c80000 - 0x182c82fff libsystem_sandbox.dylib arm64  <f82362117e823f0fbcbf9922ca025f26> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x182c84000 - 0x182c94fff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64  <fe1b1e8d0b3633c58d415c6fe8594903> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x182c98000 - 0x182c9dfff libunwind.dylib arm64  <b0067e5ea3ca3b28abc5cb7d50390363> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x182ca0000 - 0x182ca0fff libvminterpose.dylib arm64  <630bf4c89edf3935b7afe56abdb5caad> /usr/lib/system/libvminterpose.dylib
0x182ca4000 - 0x182cc9fff libxpc.dylib arm64  <fc63a0a505523f7fac2c4ea9d9662ba1> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x182ccc000 - 0x182ed1fff libicucore.A.dylib arm64  <9416014bb51e35aebdb2a9f572a2c5f8> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x182ed4000 - 0x182ee5fff libz.1.dylib arm64  <8fcb56adfdc13e9593582266b1e4ac18> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x182ee8000 - 0x183268fff CoreFoundation arm64  <182fd72b7fdf330b8dbf70db93af6b63> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x18326c000 - 0x18327cfff libbsm.0.dylib arm64  <d045301bcacc37d785d754d5c978d979> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x183280000 - 0x183280fff libenergytrace.dylib arm64  <c4ee08bffdfc3ce0990c1fbeb858f9dc> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
0x183284000 - 0x1832f5fff IOKit arm64  <0864d9c20424332d8979a4f548848c16> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x1832f8000 - 0x183318fff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64  <9cc485a12c323768a6b6e88d973bd44e> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x18331c000 - 0x183406fff libxml2.2.dylib arm64  <be446a86b5fa3620beeeb3a56a320e7b> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x183408000 - 0x18347afff Security arm64  <85e9578e7bc732ca9cced737b84163bb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x18347c000 - 0x1834d5fff SystemConfiguration arm64  <92717250c7393c44878d137773604d46> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x1834d8000 - 0x1835c0fff libsqlite3.dylib arm64  <c703a175f1c43ed28d81b839ba961183> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x1835c4000 - 0x183858fff CFNetwork arm64  <aaa7ff247b7b3357aa90f6a4dddf0697> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x18385c000 - 0x183869fff libbz2.1.0.dylib arm64  <8ebfd413e3fd3889b546857fcf554b6f> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x18386c000 - 0x183885fff liblzma.5.dylib arm64  <68bb861dc8bd3547b5ace073ed504b14> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x183888000 - 0x1838a2fff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64  <1a2c1f709f213faf81fd2223b719c899> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x1838a4000 - 0x1838cefff libarchive.2.dylib arm64  <bf6ae1a9c965363ba9f10ff0ca32ee7c> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x1838d0000 - 0x1838eefff libextension.dylib arm64  <8a88fb35fee03a36ae138e676b9a0e9f> /usr/lib/libextension.dylib
0x1838f0000 - 0x1838f1fff liblangid.dylib arm64  <cdb184e30c3c303694a96b3150520673> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x1838f4000 - 0x183b62fff Foundation arm64  <7cf4edf781cb30438b812ded8716cd95> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x183b64000 - 0x183c0ffff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <097b7e769a3439ad8fdb3abb0edc9daf> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x183c10000 - 0x183f75fff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <566419f65c9338599694a04da8e20fbf> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x183f78000 - 0x1841ddfff vImage arm64  <789df1b35e183397803583a25feff3c7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x1841e0000 - 0x184202fff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <3c655ae6f62035bbba069387c490efbb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x184204000 - 0x184217fff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64  <94d099e954d638e39ef1773639ef61af> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x184218000 - 0x184227fff libSparseBLAS.dylib arm64  <80ca4fb770613c76b2449daf05c6dc25> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparseBLAS.dylib
0x184228000 - 0x184294fff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <f4e8d68f55af3511a28a616737dcc354> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x184298000 - 0x184298fff vecLib arm64  <546ad53c3a4a36709fdf6e50b76b2ec9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x18429c000 - 0x18429cfff Accelerate arm64  <a1953e95570a3de6a923a812ffbd90ad> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x1842a0000 - 0x1847cbfff CoreGraphics arm64  <63001c4acb4135428df4b62f2f698e0f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x1847cc000 - 0x1847e0fff GraphicsServices arm64  <d8509ae0233539218bf97db29a7d31c2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x1847e4000 - 0x18482cfff AppSupport arm64  <1469530c1aa03d2486d678bed8482764> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x184830000 - 0x184903fff MobileCoreServices arm64  <2096d560a53b3fd28ff0a7f46e3ba060> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x184904000 - 0x184953fff BaseBoard arm64  <b6f2014b564430538f5252776acfa530> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x184954000 - 0x18495ffff AssertionServices arm64  <48c978bd14553765b4a7f1cee1b14c83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x184960000 - 0x184984fff BackBoardServices arm64  <207836d8c1833eeab468f622f4d0f366> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x184988000 - 0x18498bfff MobileSystemServices arm64  <6d85ae92680935bbb51db96c7a021118> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x18498c000 - 0x1849c1fff FrontBoardServices arm64  <b1a46eb324d23a51813b565ae7f04b88> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
0x1849c4000 - 0x1849cefff UserNotificationServices arm64  <74d3e76dff833048b39ae8e0ceb44140> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserNotificationServices.framework/UserNotificationServices
0x1849d0000 - 0x1849fcfff SpringBoardServices arm64  <6535787e172939d0b8abfe852a185b3d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x184a00000 - 0x184a11fff MobileKeyBag arm64  <169edc8949693d349807056d1e316f2a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x184a14000 - 0x184a1afff IOSurface arm64  <d62fd4ed209e32f98d5dbc34f9484ef4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x184a1c000 - 0x184a28fff liblockdown.dylib arm64  <36e1e9187c193410a5f7cf46e3dc7afe> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x184a2c000 - 0x184a3efff CrashReporterSupport arm64  <8e45addb6a1f379d98c9164764948fc2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x184a40000 - 0x184a42fff IOSurfaceAccelerator arm64  <65789d64b5f937e987c6f27125a38100> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurfaceAccelerator.framework/IOSurfaceAccelerator
0x184a44000 - 0x184a85fff AppleJPEG arm64  <24fc6e2cd59a318e9f59da6383bfd90d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x184a88000 - 0x184daafff ImageIO arm64  <8b10562bfdd23addb249367deb92aefd> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x184dac000 - 0x184db0fff TCC arm64  <09fcccda721f35c3936e68acf3d216a4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x184db4000 - 0x184db9fff AggregateDictionary arm64  <51bcd4b61f3739eb85fdcc4a037e3696> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x184dbc000 - 0x184dc9fff PowerLog arm64  <a50ba8508d733823be55425db249606c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PowerLog.framework/PowerLog
0x184dcc000 - 0x184e2efff libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib arm64  <59e0bc898f27370d8e4961910f891b3b> /usr/lib/libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib
0x184e30000 - 0x184e42fff CommonUtilities arm64  <194ea4f46bf537029d10e4ce8b28ca5f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x184e44000 - 0x184e5bfff libcompression.dylib arm64  <ac77f3a3cad832a7b748c30e013bbc0b> /usr/lib/libcompression.dylib
0x184e5c000 - 0x1850a6fff CoreData arm64  <aa00d2e704e333e199f8e34b3c661b12>
```

Comment: ..... Third line of the crash report: `Hardware Model:      iPad5,4`

Comment: `iPad5,4` is `iPad Air 2`

Comment: Actually i don't have iPad Air 2 so how can i find crash

Answer (score 0):

They have used an iPad Air 2 (third line of crash report). There is a [list of all Apple devices](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models) that you can use for decoding.

There are libraries that can provide hardware information directly in your app, e.g., for logging or custom crash reports.

https://github.com/sebyddd/SDVersion/blob/master/SDVersion/SDiOSVersion/SDiOSVersion.m

Comment: Actually i don't have iPad Air 2 so how can i find crash .

Comment: Well, you can try to reproduce it in iOS Simulator but be aware that this is not necessarily representative. Otherwise, if you do not have access to a physical device, e.g., from a friend, there are services like [TestObject](https://testobject.com) that provide remote access to actual physical devices. You might be able to reproduce it with one of those.